# Change detection not working when creating a dynamic component with nested input data

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-changedetection, angular-dynamic-components

I have an issue with change detection not firing the child `ngOnChanges` method for child components created dynamically using angular 13.

Here i have two dynamic components mainly

- Button Block
- Text Block

Initially when the application loads the Button block is loaded. Then on click of a button i can change that to a text block. And another button to change the details of a the loaded block is added which is not working.

renderer-component.ts

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-renderer',
  templateUrl: './renderer.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./renderer.component.css'],
})
export class RendererComponent implements OnInit {

  currentData: IBlock;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.mountButton();
  }

  mountButton() {
    this.currentData = new ButtonBlock({ type: 'button', data: 'Button text',
      attribute: { color: 'red' },
    });
  }

  mountText() {
    this.currentData = new TextBlock({ type: 'text', data: 'Hello world',
      attribute: { color: 'green' },
    });
  }

  // This is to update the component data
  updateData() {
    this.currentData.data = `Updated ${this.currentData.type}`;
    this.currentData.attribute = { color: 'yellow' };
    const data = { ...this.currentData };

    this.currentData = { ...data };
  }
}
```

dynamic-loader.component

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-dynamic-loader',
  templateUrl: './dynamic-loader.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dynamic-loader.component.css'],
})
export class DynamicLoaderComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
  @Input() data: IBlock;

  @ViewChild('viewContainerRef', { read: ViewContainerRef, static: true })
  public containerRef: ViewContainerRef;

  compMaps = [
    { key: 'button', component: ButtonBlockComponent },
    { key: 'text', component: TextBlockComponent },
  ];

  private componentRef: ComponentRef<any>;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {}

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    const dataToUpdate = { ...this.data };

    if (this.componentRef) {
      if (this.componentRef.instance.data.type === dataToUpdate.type) {
        console.log('--update trigger--');
        this.updateComponentData(dataToUpdate);
      } else {
        console.log('--load trigger--');
        this.loadComponent(dataToUpdate);
      }
    } else {
      console.log('--load trigger--');
      this.loadComponent(dataToUpdate);
    }
  }

  /**
   * Mount component
   */
  loadComponent(data: any) {
    // Get the component to render
    const componentMap = this.compMaps.find((comp) => comp.key === data.type);

    // Clear any previous references
    this.containerRef.clear();

    if (componentMap) {
      this.componentRef = this.containerRef.createComponent(componentMap.component);

      // Pass data to the component
      this.componentRef.instance['data'] = { ...data };
    }
  }

  /**
   * Update data of an already mounted component
   */
  updateComponentData(data: any) {
    // Pass data to the component
    this.componentRef.instance['data'] = { ...data };
  }
}
```

text-block-component.ts

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-text-block',
  templateUrl: './text-block.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./text-block.component.css'],
})
export class TextBlockComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
  _data: IBlock;

  @Input() set data(d: IBlock) {
    this._data = { ...d };
  }

  get data() {
    return this._data;
  }

  styles: Record<string, string>;

  constructor() {}

  // Fired first time on component mount
  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('--ngOnInit-TextBlockComponent--', this._data);
    this.styles = this._data.attribute;
  }

  // This is not firing when `updateComponentData` is called
  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    console.log('--ngOnChanges-TextBlockComponent--', this._data);
    this.styles = this._data.attribute;
  }
}
```

button-block-component.ts

```js
export class ButtonBlockComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
  _data: IBlock;

  @Input() set data(d: IBlock) {
    this._data = { ...d };
  }

  get data() {
    return this._data;
  }

  styles: Record<string, string>;

  constructor() {}

  // Fired first time on component mount
  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('--ngOnInit-ButtonBlockComponent--', this._data);
    this.styles = this._data.attribute;
  }

  // This is not firing when `updateComponentData` is called
  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    console.log('--ngOnChanges-ButtonBlockComponent--', this._data);
    this.styles = this._data.attribute;
  }
}
```

As per my requirement when the `updateData` method from `renderer-component` is called on an already mounted component (text or button) the `ngOnChanges` inside the text or button component needs to be invoked.

I also tried enabling the manual change detection for this but it doesn't seem to work either.

Here is a minimal reproduction of the issue [Dynamic component change detection issue](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-aacr6p?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdynamic%2Fdynamic-loader%2Fdynamic-loader.component.ts). You can check the console log to see the details